# How to add user to GUI sudo list?

Tags: sudo, root

When I run GUI programs like gparted or the GUI package manager, it allows me to enter the password for root or pi when it requires sudo privileges. How can I add a user to this list? I added a user to the group sudo and sudoer.d so I can `sudo apt-get` with this user, but it doesn't show as an option for GUI programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, I need to add the user to `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/60-desktop-policy.conf`.

The old file looked like this:

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-user:pi;unix-user:0
```

the new file looks like this:

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-user:pi;unix-user:newuser;unix-user:0
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.